Calculating an average of multiple polygons
I would like to "average" several polygons having a substantial intersection, e.g. these three:

Preferably using a Python library, e.g. Shapely. I don't see a suitable function there, which can be used directly. I'm not set on any formal definition of polygon averaging, just anything which looks intuitively acceptable. Any suggestions?

You could draw each of your polygons as a filled shape on an image canvas then add all the images and take their mean.

The definition of "average" is not so easy, but a possible course is to retain the pieces of area that are covered by at least 2 input polygons.
Sample script:
import geopandas as gpd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
from shapely.plotting import plot_polygon

# Input
poly1 = Polygon([(1, 1), (8, 1), (9, 9), (1, 8)])
poly2 = Polygon([(2, 1), (8, 1), (8, 8), (2, 8)])
poly3 = Polygon([(1, 2), (9, 2), (7, 9), (2, 8)])
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=[poly1, poly2, poly3])
gdf["id"] = gdf.index

# Do a self-overlay to split up the polygons in smaller parts
union_gdf = gdf.overlay(gdf, how="union", keep_geom_type=True)
# Remove the result of self-intersection of the same polygons
union_gdf = union_gdf.loc[union_gdf["id_1"] != union_gdf["id_2"]]
# Dissolve again
union_gdf.geometry = union_gdf.geometry.normalize()
union_diss_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    union_gdf.groupby(["geometry"])[["id_1"]]
    .count()
    .reset_index()
    .rename(columns={"id_1": "count"})
)

# Only retain areas where count is at least 2
average_gdf = union_diss_gdf[union_diss_gdf["count"] >= 2]
average_gdf = average_gdf.dissolve()

_, ax = plt.subplots()
plot_polygon(poly1, ax=ax, color="green", facecolor="none")
plot_polygon(poly2, ax=ax, color="blue", facecolor="none")
plot_polygon(poly3, ax=ax, color="yellow", facecolor="none")
plot_polygon(average_gdf.geometry[0], ax=ax, color="red", facecolor="none", hatch="/")
plt.show()

Result:


One approach would be to treat the input polygons as isolines of an additive embedding count...

...and find the isoline defining the median embedding count.

In extremely poorly-behaved input sets this can result in disconnected regions.

Just an idea, which can be easily implemented in Shapely:

Find a centroid of all your polygons.
Construct a ray with the origin in this centroid.
Find points of intersection of this ray and all the polygons, and compute their average point.
Repeat for as many rays as you want - all the average points will define the average polygon, provided that the number of rays is large enough and they are distributed uniformly around the centroid.

(I'll add a picture later)

I added a picture produced by a similar method. Thank you.

A slight variation on @HEKTO answer. Instead of angularly uniform rays, they are defined by vertices of one of the polygons, preferably the one with the largest number of them. Testing for malformed input data, e.g. centroid not inside all the input polygons, is omitted in this script:
import numpy as np, matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from shapely import *
from shapely.plotting import plot_line
from pathlib import Path

ls = [from_wkt(Path('ls-0.wkt').read_text()),
      from_wkt(Path('ls-1.wkt').read_text()),
      from_wkt(Path('ls-2.wkt').read_text())]
mls = MultiLineString(ls)

c = np.array(mls.centroid.coords.xy).ravel()
x0, y0, x1, y1 = mls.bounds
rScale = (x1-x0+y1-y0)/distance(Point(c), mls)
vs = []

for p in np.column_stack(ls[0].coords.xy):
  ray = LineString([c, c + rScale*(p-c)])
  vs.append(MultiPoint(intersection(mls, ray)).centroid)

avg = LinearRing(vs)
plot_line(mls, add_points=False, linewidth=1)
plot_line(avg, add_points=False, color='r')
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()

Here is an example output with "average" polygon in red. Note that in my post I was only interested in the boundary of a polygon without holes, i.e. linear ring.


Implementation with uniform angular ray distribution yields very similar result (dashed green):
def avgLinearRings(lrs):
  core = intersection_all([Polygon(e) for e in lrs])

  if core.is_empty:
    return None
  
  c = core.centroid
  x0, y0, x1, y1 = core.bounds
  vs = []

  for p in buffer(c, x1-x0+y1-y0).exterior.coords:
    vs.append(MultiPoint(intersection(lrs, LineString([c, p]))).centroid)

  return LinearRing(vs)


